# How to deal with single quote in Word VBA SQL query?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-word

I get a customer name from dropdown and use that value to query an excel spreadsheet, however, the name can contain a single quote (example: Adam's Meat). This breaks my application and how do I make a query with a variable that contains a single quote?

```
Private Sub cboCompany_Change()
            Dim customerName As String
            customerName = cboCompany.Value

rsT.Open "SELECT Customer, Postcode, Address1, Address2, State, Country FROM Customers WHERE  Customer = '" & customerName & "'", cn, adOpenStatic
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Where you specify two single quotes `''`, one will escape the other and will result in single, try to replace it like this:

```
customerName = Replace(customerName, "'", "''")
```

Comment: But then it won't match with the customer name in the spreadsheet?

Comment: The two single quote will be considered as one single quote, when the actual value match happens.

Comment: Ok, I had to change it to customerName = Replace(customerName, "'", "''") though. Thanks Sarfraz

Comment: @Morgan: Welcome and it has been about 5 years since i last worked on VB, forgot the syntax ;)

Answer (score 10):

This leaves you wide open to an SQL injection attack. I would recommend changing this to a parameterised query like this

```
Dim cmd as NEW ADODB.Command

With cmd
 .CommandText=”SELECT foo from tblBar where foo=?”
 .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@foo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, “What ever you want”)
 .ActiveConnection=dbCon
 .CommandType=adCmdText
End With

Set rst=cmd.execute
```