# ORA-00917: Missing Comma error in VB

Tags: sql, database, excel, vba, odbc

I am having a lot of trouble trying to get some VB code to work in Excel, when trying to write to a DB.  I keep getting this comma error, but i cannot for the life of me see where the comma is missing...here is the code...

```
While Not IsEmpty(startRange.Offset(i, 0))

    tentype = startRange.Offset(i, 0).Value
    tendelivery = "EMAIL"
    tenevent = startRange.Offset(i, 1).Value
    tentext = startRange.Offset(i, 2).Value
    tensubject = startRange.Offset(i, 3).Value
    tentrailer = startRange.Offset(i, 4).Value
    tenlanguage = startRange.Offset(i, 5).Value
    tenid = 10 + i




With objCommand
.ActiveConnection = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=*;Uid=*;Pwd=*"
.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TEN_TEMPLATE VALUES (" & tenid & ", " & tendelivery & ", " & tentype & ", " & tenevent & ", " & tentext & ", " & tenlanguage & ", " & tensubject & ", " & tentrailer & ")"
.Execute

End With

    i = i + 1
Wend
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Brett

Comment: i suggest you to change your password

Comment: np, btw usually an insert statement requires the column names `INSERT INTO TABLE (column1,column2) VALUES (value1,value2)`. isnt that missing in your command?

Comment: I think that's only if you want to specify what data you want to insert, leaving other fields as NULL.  All of my fields are non-NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could one of your values have an embedded comma or, more likely, a quote? That may screw up the resulting SQL string even though your building looks good.

Comment: There is a good chance it could be the case - is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Use Excel Replace function to replace one quote with two quotes which will be like one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975042/how-to-deal-with-single-quote-in-word-vba-sql-query (Word, but same VBA concept). 

To verify what is happening, you can use MsgBox to see the completes string. Before execute, put MsgBox .CommandText

Comment: Brett, also, from the names I'm guessing some of your fields are text. Those need to be enclosed in quotes for the SQL. So if TenText has "ABCDE" the SQL statement should look like "INSERT..... , 'ABCDE', ...". Your build should be something like (note the single quotes)

.CommandText = "INSERT ... & ", '" & tentext & "', " & ../ & ")"

Comment: Thanks Asantaballa, the extra quotes made all the difference.