# VBA to Write SQL grabbing table info

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to work through a Problem. 
We have a table has a column for Brands and one of those Brands uses an apostrophe. 
IE brand = "Bob's". from table Cataloginfo

In my VBA code I have it building to SQL using

```
WHERE z.brand = '" & strBrand & "'
```

The hope here is that in the SQL code I will see it as "Bob''s" so it will work in SQL rather than what I'm seeing it as right now which is "Bob's" which is how it is in the table. Is this even possible?

This is being built in VBA to run as a passthrough to SQL Server Mgt studio.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: There is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975042/how-to-deal-with-single-quote-in-word-vba-sql-query) on how to escape single quotes.  Kevin Ross's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3975561/2572928) mentions [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).  If you've not come across it before it is worth reading up on.

Comment: Thanks guys this is perfect! I'm still learning SQL and what I can do with it so these are invaluable resources!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When SQL Server encounters two successive single-quotes, it only sees one single-quote. So you would double-up on the single quotes, like this:

```
WHERE z.brand = '" & REPLACE(strBrand,"'","''") & "'
```